# Can we create table in SQL by passing column information from Azure blob using Azure data flow or Azure data factory?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have CSV files that contain SQL Table column information as Column_Name, Data_Type, Primary_Key. But not contain any data, Can we use Azure Data flow or Azure Data Factory to create table by using these type of CSV file for particular table in SQL.

Comment: You can convert that dataset into a dynamic CREATE TABLE statement by many means. You can probably run that CREATE TABLE statement inside a `Lookup` activity. Yes you can probably do it in ADF. No it is not practical to do it inside ADF. If you had another tool that could do the conversion it would be much more practical. That tool could be Azure Functions, Azure Automation, or a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Hi Asif Khan, If my answer is helpful for you, you can make it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According my experience about Data Factory,  we can not pass the csv file content which  contains SQL Table column information as Column_Name, Data_Type, Primary_Key to create table in SQL.

Data Factory or Data flow all couldn't achieve that.

You also reference the another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61181031/10549281

Hope this helps.